# how do I limit the average into 2 decimal places in getting the rating?

Tags: php, codeigniter

[average rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc2gF.png)

Here is my code! How do I get the average that has only 2 decimal places?

```
 public function getAveRating($restoid){ 
      $where=array(
           "restoid"=>$restoid
           );
      $this->db->where($where);
      $this->db->select_avg('rate');
      $query = $this->db->get('ratings')->first_row('array');
      return $query['rate'];
 }
```

how do I limit the average into 2 decimal places in getting the rating?

Comment: Googling for "PHP format number" yields zero results? Same thing for Googling "php 2 decimal places"

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/round

```
 public function getAveRating($restoid){ 
      $where=array(
           "restoid"=>$restoid
           );
      $this->db->where($where);
      $this->db->select_avg('rate');
      $query = $this->db->get('ratings')->first_row('array');
      return round($query['rate'], 2);
 }
```

Comment: .. Then, please mark this answer as correct answer @Yuki.

Answer (score 0):

Change `return $query['rate'];` to `return round($query['rate'],2);`